# Python - 3 month moving averages for the year

Tags: python, average

Basically I created a function that allows me to show the following output:

```
Jan - Mar 24.00
Feb - Apr 25.00
Mar - May 26.00
Apr - Jun 27.00
May - Jul 28.00
Jun - Aug 29.00
Jul - Sep 30.00
Aug - Oct 31.00
Sep - Nov 32.00
Oct - Dec 44.00
```

I did the following function, but i think it is too big. Can i have some help in reducing the size of this please? All these values are stored in lists.

```
def movingMean():
    average = sum(rainValues[0:3])
    finalavg = float(average)//3
    print(months[0],"-",months[2],"%.2f" %finalavg)

    average = sum(rainValues[1:4])
    finalavg = float(average)//3
    print(months[1],"-",months[3],"%.2f" %finalavg)

    average = sum(rainValues[2:5])
    finalavg = float(average)//3
    print(months[2],"-",months[4],"%.2f" %finalavg)

    average = sum(rainValues[3:6])
    finalavg = float(average)//3
    print(months[3],"-",months[5],"%.2f" %finalavg)

    average = sum(rainValues[4:7])
    finalavg = float(average)//3
    print(months[4],"-",months[6],"%.2f" %finalavg)

    average = sum(rainValues[5:8])
    finalavg = float(average)//3
    print(months[5],"-",months[7],"%.2f" %finalavg)

    average = sum(rainValues[6:9])
    finalavg = float(average)//3
    print(months[6],"-",months[8],"%.2f" %finalavg)

    average = sum(rainValues[7:10])
    finalavg = float(average)//3
    print(months[7],"-",months[9],"%.2f" %finalavg)

    average = sum(rainValues[8:11])
    finalavg = float(average)//3
    print(months[8],"-",months[10],"%.2f" %finalavg)

    average = sum(rainValues[9:])
    finalavg = float(average)//3
    print(months[9],"-",months[11],"%.2f" %finalavg)
```

Comment: Although I dont have a python background generally with repetition like that you can probably put it in some sort of loop

Comment: Start by coding the start and end indices of the rainValues you want to average as *variables* rather than hard-coded constants.  So instead of seeing things like `rainValues[7:10]` we should see something like `rainValue[startIndex:stopIndex]` where `startIndex` and `stopIndex` are variables under your program's control.  They could increase automatically in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop with an index

```
for i in range(len(rainValues)-2):
    average = sum(rainValues[i:i+3]) // 3
    print(months[i],"-",months[i+2],"%.2f" % average)
```

Though you should realize that the // 3 divides to an int, and you will always have two 0s after the dot.  also, format is preferred.

```
for i in range(len(rainValues - 2)):
    average = sum(rainValues[i:i+3]) / 3
    print("{} - {} {:.2f}".format(months[i], months[i+2], average)
```

There are nicer ways to do this with generators, but for the sake of keeping this short, this works.

---

UPDATE: For a generator-based solution, you can use what I call *sliding_window* a term taken from networking.

```
import itertools

def sliding_window(iterable, win_sz):
    for i in itertools.count():
        ret = iterable[i:i+win_sz]
        if len(ret) != win_sz: break
        yield ret
```

This can then be used with 3 as the window size.  If you wanted you could also take the size as an argument to your function, and provide varying-length averages.

```
for vals in sliding_window(rainValues, 3):
    average = sum(vals) / len(vals)
    print(average)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you have posted I would simplify it down to something that looks like this.

```
def movingMean(): 
    #Assuming python3, use xrange in python 2
    #Generate numbers 0 - 9
    for x in range(0, 10):
        #Hardcoding 9 because you are dealing with dates and this won't change
        if x == 9:
            average = average_calculator(rainValues[x:])
            print(months[x],"-",months[],"%.2f" %average)
        else:
            average = average_calculator(rainValues[x:x+3])
            print(months[x],"-",months[x+3],"%.2f" %average)


    #Function assumes you are passing float into it, returns an int as it is
def average_calculator(sum):
    return sum // 3
```

When looking at the code you posted it only does 2 things, 1 - calculate the average and 2 - print the average. So I split the program into a reusable function to calculate the average and a for loop with a print statement.

Also just a side note about average_calculator:
The cast here inside this function is unnecessary as I am assuming that sum will be a float. Also I wrote it to mimic what you are doing exactly. However // is the floor division operator in python - 9 // 2 = 4 This means that the function will always return an int and even if you cast it to a float it will become 9.0 // 2.0 = 4.0. I'm not totally sure what you are doing in your program but just in case you were not aware because it looks like you want a float for printing like `9.32` or something. To return a float division result you can cast to a float in Python 2 or just use the normal division operator in Python 3. (You could also import from `__future__` in python 2)

This code:

```
    average = sum(rainValues[0:3])
    finalavg = float(average)//3
```

becomes a call to average_calculator that would look like this:

```
average_calculator(sum(rainValues[0:3]))
```

this returns a float representing the calculated average but instead of repeating this code for each set of months it works with variables so it can be reused.

Then you have your print statements that look like this:

```
print(months[0],"-",months[2],"%.2f" %finalavg)
```

In general it is bad practice to hard code numbers like this although it is up to your discretion as they are months and there will always be 12 months no matter what.

I replaced your print statements with this:

```
#Assuming python3, use xrange in python 2
#Generate numbers 0 - 9
for x in range(0, 10):
    #Hardcoding 9 because you are dealing with dates and this won't change
    if x == 9:
        average = average_calculator(rainValues[x:])
        print(months[x],"-",months[],"%.2f" %average)
    else:
        average = average_calculator(rainValues[x:x+3])
        print(months[x],"-",months[x+3],"%.2f" %average)
```

so that it loops through changing the value of x, calculating each average using a call to `average_calculator()` and printing each average. I used an if statement to account for the last 3 months as this print statement was different than all the rest.

I was not able to test this code because the code you posted was incomplete and there is no dataset but I believe this should work fine, if you have any problems with it let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) It really helped to understand how to reduce the code and how the code works!

Comment: No problem, consider marking it as the best answer if you feel like I was able to completely explain the process and completely answer your question